# Using __lt__() method belongs to the parent class even if it is overrided

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,grade):
        self.__name=name
        self.__grade=grade
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self.__name<other.__name
    def __repr__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.__name,self.__grade)
 
class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,grade):
        Person.__init__(self, name, grade)
    def __lt__(self,other):
        return self._Person__grade<other._Person__grade
    
L=[]
student1=Student('Xavi',90)
student2=Student('Richard',100)
L.append(student1)
L.append(student2)
L.sort()
print(L)
```

---

```
Expected Output:
[Richard 100,Xavi 90]
```

Hello, even if I override the `__lt__` method in the subclass, I still want to use the `__lt__()` method in the superclass, how can I do that? I think instead of using `L.sort()` directly, we need to call `__lt__` method of the class `Person`, but I dont know how to do that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I still want to use the lt() method in the superclass"? Do you mean that you want to get the result from the superclass method and then add another condition as well? Better yet, define **in words** what it means for one Student to be "less than" another?

Comment: If you want to use both, why override it?

Comment: Because I override the lt method in the subclass, it makes the comparison according to grades, but I want it to make comparison according to names.

Comment: @mapf, I want to learn how to use desired lt method outside the class.

Comment: You didn't override the attribute, so you can use `self.__grade` in place of `self._Person__grade`.

Comment: Rather than trying to access the parent class's method, use the `key` argument to `sort`: `L.sort(key=lambda x: x.grade)` or `L.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)`. (Get rid of the `__`-prefixed names; they are more trouble than they are worth).

Comment: `self._Person__grade<other._Person__grade` **no**. If you are doing that in your subclass **then just don't use double-underscore name-mangling**

Answer (score 2):

An object can only have one `__lt__` method. There's no way to specify that `sort()` should use a different method than other comparisons.

Instead, you can specify a key in the `sort()` call so it sorts by names instead of using the `__lt__` method of the object itself.

```
L.sort(key = lambda(s): s._Person__name)
```

or

```
import operator
L.sort(key = operator.attrgetter("_Person__name"))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, but is there any way without using lambda expressions? I mean, for example, we can say something like Person.__lt__() outside the classes. I actually need this kind of expression.

Comment: `sort()` doesn't let you specify the comparison function, only a key function.

Comment: Ok, so we have to use lambda expressions to solve it.

Comment: You could also use `operator.attrgetter("_Person__name")`

Comment: @blit no, you don't ever *need* to use a lambda expression. Ever.

Comment: @blit You could also define a method that returns the name, and use that.